# Sqoop import hive ORC

Tags: hive

All,

I have question for sqooping , I am sqooping around 2tb of data for one table and then need to write ORC table wit h that . What's best way to achieve

1) sqoop all data in dir1 as text and write HQL to load into ORC table , where script fail for vertex issue

2) sqoop data in chucks and process and append into hive table ( have you done this ? )

3) sqoop hive import to write all data to hive ORC table

Which is best way ?

Comment: Kindly Google it. SO is not a recommendation site!

Answer (score 0):

Option three will be better because you dont need to create a hive table and again loading data into it and storing that data in orc format it is a long process for 2tb of data so its better to give in sqoop so it can directly push the data into hive table with orc format but when you are returning data from hive table to rdbms you have to use sqoopserde